# Ember.handlebars boundIf didn't call calculated property

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I try to migrate project form Ember cli 0.1.2 to 0.1.15. Current problem is next:

I have can-helper. It works fine at older ember but at newer version all can-blocks are absent. Can-helper use calculated property in model, so i try to set debugger into calculation function - it work on 0.1.2 and didn't work at 0.1.15

Original ember - 1.7.0-beta.1
Try migrate to ember - 1.9.1

As i found implementation of boundIf helper was changed. Have anybody some ideas / experience with such trouble?

P.S. code of can-helper is below

```
var get = Ember.get, isGlobalPath = Ember.isGlobalPath, normalizePath = Ember.Handlebars.normalizePath,
  IS_BINDING = Ember.IS_BINDING;

var getProp = function(context, property, options) {
  if (isGlobalPath(property)) {
    return get(property);
  } else {
    var path = normalizePath(context, property, options.data);
    return get(path.root, path.path);
  }
};

export default function(permissionName, property, options) {
  var attrs, context, key, path, permission;

  // property is optional, if we've only got 2 arguments then the property contains our options
  if (!options) {
    options = property;
    property = null;
  }

  context = (options.contexts && options.contexts[0]) || this;

  attrs = {};

  // if we've got a property name, get its value and set it to the permission's content
  // this will set the passed in `post` to the content eg:
  // {{#can editPost post}} ... {{/can}}
  if (property) {
    attrs.content = getProp(context, property, options);
  }

  // if we've got any options, find their values eg:
  // {{#can createPost project=project user=App.currentUser}} ... {{/can}}
  for (key in options.hash) {
    if (!options.hash.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      continue;
    }
    path = options.hash[key];
    if (options.hashTypes[key] === 'STRING') {
      if (IS_BINDING.test(key)) {
        attrs[key.slice(0, -7)] = getProp(context, path, options);
      }
      else {
        attrs[key] = path;
      }
    }
    else {
      attrs[key] = getProp(context, path, options);
    }
  }

  // find & create the permission with the supplied attributes
  permission = this.get('container').lookup('permissions:main').get(permissionName, attrs);

  // ensure boundIf uses permission as context and not the view/controller
  // otherwise it looks for 'can' in the wrong place
  options.contexts = null;


  // bind it all together and kickoff the observers
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.boundIf.call(permission, "can", options);
}
```

in template it used as

```
  {{#can read model="contact"}}
    <div class="panel">
      {{#link-to 'contacts' id="nav-to-contacts" class="main-menu-root-item" title="Contacts"}}
        Contacts
      {{/link-to}}
    </div>
  {{/can}}
```

Can is computed property at permission

```
can: function() {
  var model = get(this, 'model'),
    field = get(this, 'field'),
    permission = rules.findBy('name', model);


  return permission && permission.read &&
         (field ? permission.read.contains(field) : permission.read.length);
}.property()
```

At older version i can stop inside it with debugger statement, but after updating - can't
It's possible errors on observers changes of model, but it should be called at least once ( on initial rendering )  - as i understand

Comment: What version of ember are you using now and what were you using before?  Also do you think you can include some code of what your .hbs file looks like I'm a little unclear from your description.

Comment: Update my post. What code do you interested in? I can't understand cause ember's helpers method signatures are the same in both versions

Comment: Please attach the code of `can` helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason in wrong context for getting property
Please look here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10692